# Adding the last element to string after array

Tags: java

My storage string gives me all the digits in want besides the last, I know its because the last digit has nothing to compare to the right. Can I add the last digit to the end of my string somehow,

```
    for(int i = 0;i < othercontent.length -1 ;i++ )
    {
        if(othercontent[i] != othercontent[i + 1])
        {
            storage = storage + othercontent[i]; 

        }
    }
```

Comment: What you want to accomplish at the end?

Comment: Can you please give a sample input/output?

Comment: I have sorted and now I am getting rid of all the duplicates in the array

Comment: the whole program is huge so its kinda hard to give an input output example but say AABBBCCC will go in AB will come out I want ABC

Comment: I am only trying to get rid of duplicates not the last element and I cant use the API methods

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < othercontent.length ;i++ )
{
    if(i == 0 || othercontent[i] != othercontent[i - 1])
    {
        storage = storage + othercontent[i]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am little wary to add additional checks inside the loop. Instead, you can push the 0th iteration outside.

Answer (score 1):

if othercontent is String array :

```
TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(othercontent));
othercontent = set.toArray(new String[0]);
for (String string : othercontent) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

if othercontent is String :

```
String othercontent = "ZZZZQQWEDDODRAABBNNNNO";
LinkedList<Character> list = new LinkedList<>();
for (Character character : othercontent.toCharArray()) {
    list.add(character);
}
TreeSet<Character> set = new TreeSet<>(list);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Character character : set) {
    builder.append(character);
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

not only sorting , but also removing dublicates are solved with this code

OUTPUT :

```
ABDENOQRWZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you reached the last element:

```
for(int i = 0;i < othercontent.length -1; i++ ) {
    if(othercontent[i] != othercontent[i + 1]) {
        storage = storage + othercontent[i]; 
    }
    //only gets executed if the last iteration is reached
    if(i==othercontent.length-2) {
        storage = storage + othercontent[i+1];
    }
}
```

Or, instead of using a condition, just write this after your loop:

```
storage = storage + othercontent[othercontent.length-1];
```

Comment: You don't need to add additional condition inside the loop, instead you can just add the last char outside the loop (with some additional checks if needed). something like storage = storage + othercontent[othercontent.length-1];

Answer (score 0):

You can add the last digit to your string outside of for loop as it doesn't require to check any condition

```
 for(int i = 0;i < othercontent.length -1; i++ ) {
    if(othercontent[i] != othercontent[i + 1]) {
        storage = storage + othercontent[i]; 
    }

}

 storage = storage + othercontent[othercontent.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < othercontent.length -1 ; ++i )    {
    if(othercontent[i] != othercontent[i + 1]) {
        storage = storage + othercontent[i];
    }
}
if(othercontent.length>0){
    storage = storage + othercontent[othercontent.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for the duplicates, you should do something like this outside the loop.

```
if(othercontent.length>0 && storage[storage.length-1] ! = othercontent[othercontent.length-1])
{
    storage = storage+othercontent[othercontent.length-1];
}
```